What's the "best" sound level meter available on the market?
I am thinking of purchasing a sound level meter to use for opportunistic measurements of shorebird vocalizations in the field this summer (Utqiagvik, Alaska). There are many options online, but I'm wondering if the community has any suggestions about particular makes/models for this type of application. I haven't made measurements of this type before.
Thanks, all!

still looking for additional opinions on this! I'm hoping to compile a list of a few best options (from top of the line to most budget-friendly)

What data are you measuring, to what end?  What accuracy is needed?  Do you need to know the quantitative assessment in the field?  There's a lot to be said for capturing sound in the field using the right microphone and a digital recorder and performing analysis on a computer later.  (Even a phone with an external microphone may meet the need, depending on what it is.).   I perform acoustical analyses of lecture halls and the like using an instrumentation microphone and laptop, but am unfamiliar with the birding world's needs.

The question lacks sufficient definition of "best" (or does everyone but me, admittedly not a birder, know what qualities are needed?).  SPL precision?  Speed of response?  Geolocation tag?  Battery life?  Weather resistance?  Handheld vs mountable?  Directionality?  Flatness of frequency response?  Cost?  For any and all, how much is good enough, and which do you prioritize?  The only answer I can see is, "It depends...."  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

@MadMonty yeah, I understand your concern. The conceit of the Bioacoustics SE was to provide a space for bioacousticians to come together and ask/answer relevant questions. In particular, there was an interest in providing resources for those who may be starting in the field with little on-the-ground support in the form of other experts in acoustics.

@MadMonty I've been a part of this field for 6+ years, but still find all the time that there are gaps in my knowledge. I wrote this question because there wasn't anything similar on the Bioacoustics SE so far, and I thought it might be useful to the NEXT person looking to do something similar. My hope was not to get one answer, but to compile experiences across bioacousticians.

I would be interested in what you and your colleagues with field experience have found valuable in a measurement device.  Perhaps their answers would be even more helpful if the question were edited to ask, "Which... and why?"  I could imagine that answers will would vary depending on the scenario.

Via Holger Klinck (Cornell Lab of Ornithology) on LinkedIn:
"These guys make the best: https://www.larsondavis.com/Products/sound-level-meters "
In case anyone ever has the same question :)

ok, but based on what?

@MadMonty, measurement accuracy in this case. The one suggested here is pretty much top of the line for sound pressure level measurements. It’s actually not what I ended up buying, though, because it’s quite expensive. I’m planning on coming back and adding a longer answer explaining that, what I DID get, and how it worked for me after the field season, but I’ve been swamped lately.

Please back this up.  To be useful, answers on SE need to be more than mere opinion.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
